# Why do my PDFs from Hebrewbooks.org get cut off?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Many posters on our site use hebrewbooks.org to reference sources.  Recently, the PDFs from Hebrewbooks do not display correctly on my PC.  Initially, I can read an entire page, but after a couple of clicks back and forth, the same pages display a white, blank bottom half.  My PDF reader is up to date and this does not happen with any other PDFs.  Does anyone know what my problem is and how I can fix it.

---

**Update:** I switched browsers from chrome to ie and so far have not had this issue with ie.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooksqa.org/

Comment: [Link to that question.](http://www.hebrewbooksqa.org/19)

Comment: Which pdf reader are you using? Can you provide us with some more details, like Mac/Windows? Which version? What PDF software?

Comment: The infamous white screen usually occurs due to an encoding problem (font, for example). It may be their PDFs that are corrupt, but no way to tell without sufficient information.

Comment: @studiohack, I'm on Windows 7 using Adobe X.  I'm not sure how to ID which software the site is using.

Comment: @RandolphWest, If others who share the aforementioned site would share in this problem, I would know the issue is not on my side.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @studiohack, also, if I am viewing the PDFs on their website and not as a standalone, would my reader make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 8.0.552.215, Chrome has used its own built in PDF viewer, which means Chrome no longer uses the plugin Adobe provides to render PDFs inside the browser. It sounds like Chrome's plugin is unable to handle some aspect of Hebrewbooks' PDFs while Adobe (and browsers that use the Adobe plugin) can.

If you want to disable Chrome's PDF viewer and use Adobe's, do the following [(source)](http://blogs.adobe.com/vikrant/2010/12/use-adobe-plugins-to-view-pdfs-inside-google-chrome/):

1. Type `chrome://plugins` in the address bar
2. Disable `Chrome PDF Viewer`
3. If not already enabled, enable Adobe Acrobat/Adobe Reader

Comment: chrome reader was enabled and adobe disable.  Reversing that solved the problem.  Thank you.